# Find the last entry of a data in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need find the latest entry by comparing two columns My table as follows[image]

I need to find the latest entry of each player may he went out in Striker or in Nonstricker .how to find the last entry of each player by comparing Striker and NonStricker column,ie I need sthe result a follows
[image]

it shows the last entry of RR_2 and RR_3

Comment: could you post some more data ! and required output?

Comment: In What scenario to neglect the id 3

Comment: What is the logic to find the last entry?

Comment: RR_2 is exist only in id 1, it doesnot exist in following rows so RR_2 last entry is First Row, RR_3 exist in 2nd row it doesnot exist in the following row so the last entry for RR_3 is 2nd row.May be the last entry  in Stricker or Nonstricker. I need the last entry only

Comment: Are you defining last based on the `Bbid` column? I.e. higher values indicate later rows? Tables, in and of themselves, have **no** order.